# Uncaught ReferenceError in Framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I am getting this error while integrating a simple Javascript code in www.framework7.io

This is JS I want to integrate http://ssdmm.org/if/simple/562.html and whenever I select a value from drop down I get this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):1)
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2.0**

Ok now I understand; First off all the Framework7 DOM https://framework7.io/docs/dom.html needs to be taken. I have successfully resolved the error by running the following code in the Console. However when I include it in the JS file it seems not to be working.

```
$$(document).on('change', function () {
          var value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
          myApp.alert(value);

          if(value == 'M3'){
            var a = '1.8'; //value of m
            var b = 'M3'; // value of d
            var c = '7'; //value of e
            var d = '5.5'; // value of s

          } else if(value == 'M4'){
            var a = '2.2';
            var b = 'M4';
            var c = '8.9';
            var d = '7';
          } else if(value == 'M5'){
            var a = '2.7';
            var b = 'M5';
            var c = '10.2';
            var d = '8';
          } else if(value == 'M6'){
            var a = '3.2';
            var b = 'M6';
            var c = '12.7';
            var d = '10';
          } else if(value == 'M8'){
            var a = '4';
            var b = 'M8';
            var c = '16.5';
            var d = '13';

          } else if(value == 'M10'){
            var a = '5';
            var b = 'M10';
            var c = '21.5';
            var d = '17';

          } else {
            var a = '';
            var b = '';
            var c = '';
            var d = '';
          }

          document.getElementById("Row").innerHTML = '<td align="center" width="16%"><b><font color="#000" face="Verdana" size="2">'+a+'</font></b></td>' +
             '<td align="center" width="16%"><b><font color="#000" face="Verdana" size="2">'+b+'</font></b></td>'+
             '<td align="center" width="16%"><b><font color="#000" face="Verdana" size="2">'+c+'</font></b></td>'+
             '<td align="center" width="16%"><b><font color="#000" face="Verdana" size="2">'+d+'</font></b></td>';

      });
```

Anyone who is aware on how can I assign this script to a specific page in Framework7, can easily help me resolve this error.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Utpal

Comment: function `myFunction` is not defined, your image is not related to problem.

Comment: I am new to JS, however this is how we declare a function. `function  myFunction(sel) { } ` correct me if wrong. This is there in the project. You can refer the JS code from the source code of the link.

Comment: I see. Try to insert your script above of select